# "You are billed for the first 5 minutes and per second after."

Tags: usage

This appears in one promotional mailing list. It is from a telco service provider.

> You are billed for the first 5 minutes and per second after.

After reading the entire content, I understand it means we will be billed for the first five minutes regardless if we end the call in less than 5 minutes. After the first 5 minutes, we will be billed by per second.

Without any additional context, does the above sentence convey the message correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's how I would read it. Also, billing per second sounds very expensive, unless they charge *very* small amounts per second!

Comment: @randomhead I'd read that as an advantage; If my call last 5 minutes and 1 second I'd only be billed for that, rather than rounding up to the next minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You could also view this as being charged at a specific per-second rate, but with a minimum charge of 300 seconds per call, regardless of whether the call is shorter than that or not.